# How to use a for loop inside a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, activerecord, migration

I'm very new to RoR and trying to write a migration which adds 200 similar columns to my database. For each invoice in a table I would like to collect the line items in separate columns.  Each invoice could have up to 200 items.

Here is the code I wrote (it does not loop through like I would like it to):

```
def change
  create_table :invoices do |t|
    200.times do |i|
      t.string :itemdescription_i
      t.decimal :itemqty_i
      t.decimal :itemunitprice_i
      t.decimal :itemextendedprice_i
    end
  end
end
```

How could I create the columns using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to create a linking table called invoice_item to your invoice table. Any related invoice items would be added to this table referencing the invoice. Then in your code you could just retrieve an invoice and call invoice.invoice_items

```
  create_table :invoice_items do |t|
    t.references :invoice
    t.string :itemdescription
    t.decimal :itemqty
    t.decimal :itemunitprice
    t.decimal :itemextendedprice
  end
```

Comment: Really good point thanks for taking the time to show me how to properly structure my database.

Answer (score 1):

```
  200.times do |i|
    t.string :"itemdescription_#{i}"
    t.decimal :"itemqty_#{i}"
    t.decimal :"itemunitprice_#{i}"
    t.decimal :"itemextendedprice_#{i}"
  end
```

*But note it's horrible database design.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `t.column` will take a string. And wouldn't you agree that `:"string"` looks terribly ugly? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I knew that, just show how to create dynamic symbol for the op, of course, string works too.